# chruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-2.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chruby

With chruby, why won't `ruby-2.2.0` in `.ruby-version` work, whereas `chruby ruby-2.2.0` will?

```
% whoami
mark
% sudo su myapp
% cd /home/www/myapp/
% whoami
chruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-2.2.0
myapp
% cat .ruby-version
ruby-2.2.0
% which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
% chruby ruby-2.2.0
% which ruby
/home/www/myapp/.rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
```

Full transcript of Ruby on Rails deployment:

https://gist.github.com/dt1973/7b99dfb75bd26e1e5ed7

Answer (score 5):

In `.ruby-version` just put `2.2.0`, i.e.

```
echo 2.2.0 > .ruby-version
```